Infinispan default jgroups configuration file location
What is the default location from which the infinispan takes the jgroup configuration if it has not been configured in startup? I have found 2 files in default-config however it does not looks like those files are being used.
I am using generic library that may use different cache types therefore i can not just modify the GlobalConfiguration -> transport with required attribute ( at least this is not a preferred option ).
Also, can the configuration file be provided as CLI parameter?

Infinispan has a number of default stacks which are listed https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/embedding/embedding.html#default-jgroups-stacks_cluster-transport
The default stack is udp, so default-configs/default-jgroups-udp.xml.
The stack can be referenced by name in the infinispan/cache-container/transport/stack configuration attribute.
I'm not sure what you mean by "CLI parameter". Since this is embedded, I assume you mean a system property. If this is the case, unfortunately the answer is no, but you could ask for an RFE using https://issues.redhat.com/projects/ISPN/

Hi. The problem was that i removed the ping , and added dnsping to UDP file, but did not set ip_mcast to false. As result it ignored the changes.. what made me think that its not the file its using...
Thanks
